# Setting up network interfaces using linux sysfiles

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

Good day,
I am trying to set up network subinterfaces for my IP address using `ifconfig`.
Also i need to configure network interfaces in the Linux sysfile.

I know the manual for `ifconfig` but i am having troubles with its config. Should it be like...

```
ifconfig 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask 255.255.255.0
```

...or am i missing something?

Thanks for replies, also am i doing the bind9 dns configuration right?
name.conf.local adding at the end:

```
zone "202.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/202.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
zone "201.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/201.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
};
zone "my.domain" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/my.domain";
};
```

where my.domain is name of my domain (well, kinda obvious)

now creating the `202.168.192.in-addr.arpa` file

```
$TTL 1s
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
1 ; Serial
604800 ; Refresh
86400 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS localhost.
000 IN PTR localhost.
000 IN PTR hostn1
000 IN PTR hostn2
```

where 000 is last byte of my address

Similar for `201.168.192.in-addr.arpa`

```
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL 1s
@ IN SOA localhost. root.localhost. (
1 ; Serial
604800 ; Refresh
86400 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@ IN NS localhost.
XXX IN PTR localhost.
XXX IN PTR host1
XXY IN PTR host2
```

and for the `my.domain` file

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL 1s
@ IN SOA ns.my.domain. root.ns.my.domain. (
1 ; Serial
604800 ; Refresh
86400 ; Retry
2419200 ; Expire
604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
IN NS ns
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1
ns IN A IP
host1 IN A IP
host2 IN A IP
hostn1 IN A IP
hostn2 IN A IP
```

Comment: You are missing the interface, in my case is `eth0`: `ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`

Comment: Only one question/topic per post, please!

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow Linux fella ! In debian setting network subinterfaces goes like that:

`ifconfig eth0:0 IP netmask 255.255.255.0`

You should also edit etc/network/interfaces

`//do not remove anything!!
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
 address IP
 netmask 255.255.255.0
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
 address IP
 netmask 255.255.255.0`

then restart

`ifconfig eth0:0 down
ifconfig
/etc/init.d/networking restart
ifconfig`

after that you can

`ping IP`

to check if everything everything is allright

Comment: You should probably note somewhere in your answer that it's ubuntu (or possibly debian) centric. Other distros vary in the path and names of interface config files.

Comment: sure, I forgot about that